# Ajax.BeginForm not posting model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax, viewmodel, ajax.beginform

This has been asked multiple times but I cannot find a satisfying answer. I tried all the suggestions on similar posts without any success.

When I'm using an Ajax.BeginForm it won't post my updated values to the controller. It's always a default ViewModel.

```
 //Viewmodel
 public class MyViewModel
 {
      [Required]
      public int Prop1 {get; set;}
      [Required]
      public int Prop2 {get; set;}
 }

 //Controller action
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Test(MyViewModel model)
 {
      return PartialView("_partialview");
 }

 //View
 @model Namespace.MyViewModel;

 @using(Ajax.BeginForm("Test", Model, new AjaxOptions()
 {
      UpdateTargetId = "divName",
      HttpMethod = "POST",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
 }))
 {
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Prop1)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Prop2)
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 }
```

I have tried multiple suggestions but the posted value inside the controller is always a default MyViewModel without updated values.

I also tried different variations to post the values:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Test", new { model }, new AjaxOptions()
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Test", new { model = @Model }, new AjaxOptions()
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Test", new { model = 
     new Namespace.MyViewModel{ Prop1 = @Model.Prop1, Prop2 = @Model.Prop2 } }, new AjaxOptions()
```

Used bundles:

```
"~/bundles/jqueryval"
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-*"
```

I really don't know what else to try to get the updated values posted.

Comment: You seem to be attempting to add your model in the route values. It should be just `@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Test", new AjaxOptions() {...`

Comment: I left the model out of it now and I still get nothing posted. Checked all the related topics aswell, I really have no clue anymore.

Comment: Have tested you code (but added `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Prop1)` in the view (ditto for `Prop2`) and it works fine. In the post method, `model` contains the values I entered in the textboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the help Stephen, it's solved now. My Ajax.BeginForm was inside an EditorTemplate. So I was expecting the wrong parameter-type in the post-method. Once I changed the parameter to the actual pagemodel (the one that embed the editortemplate) the values where there inside `model.myviewmodel`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solve this with this:

put "id" in Method

```
public ActionResult StolenBadge(StolenDocViewModel id)
{
   var obj = id
   ... rest of code ...
}
```

in Ajax Form equals "id = Model"

```
  @model WFAccess.Models.ViewModels.StolenDocViewModel

  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("StolenBadge", "Requests", new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "document-body",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        LoadingElementId = "document-loading",
        OnBegin = "ClearBody('document-body')"
    }, new { id = Model }))
    {
        ... rest of form ...
    }
```